# How to binding Max Function Textbox1 To Textbox2?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, data-binding, binding, textbox

i use vb.net 2008, i want binding txtEmpNo To txtRate. but i checked column it's correct.

**Error** "Cannot bind to the property or column Rate on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember"

**This Code:**

```
Private Sub txtEmpNo_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtEmpNo.KeyPress
        Dim da3 As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds3 As New DataSet()

        Dim sqlRate As String = "SELECT Max(Rate) From EmployeeSalary WHERE EmployeeRun = '" & txtEmpNo.Text.ToString & "'"
        da3 = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlRate, Conn)
        da3.Fill(ds3, "EmployeeRun")
        If ds3.Tables("EmployeeRun").Rows.Count > 0 Then
            txtRate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ds3.Tables("EmployeeRun"), "Rate"))
            txtRate.DataBindings.Clear()
        Else
            txtRate.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your query,set Rate alias to `max(rate)`

Change:

```
 Dim sqlRate As String = "SELECT Max(Rate) From EmployeeSalary WHERE EmployeeRun = '" & txtEmpNo.Text.ToString & "'"
```

If you execute this query the result will be

```
|(No ColumnName)|
| max rate value|
```

To

```
 Dim sqlRate As String = "SELECT Max(Rate) as Rate From EmployeeSalary WHERE EmployeeRun = '" & txtEmpNo.Text.ToString & "'"
```

this will show

```
|Rate           |
|max rate value |
```

Best Regards